# Kubernetes: How to simulate a liveness probe on distroless containers?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod which keeps restarting because of failed liveliness probes:

```
Events:
   ... Container ... failed liveness probe, will be restarted
```

I suspect the the liveliness timeout of 1 sec is the issue here.

The liveliness probe is defined as follows:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 80
    scheme: HTTP
```

Is there a way to simulate the HTTP request with `kubectl` to take a few samples on the response time?

`exec`ing into the container and running `curl` is not an option, because the container is distroless.

Felix

Comment: You can port-forward to the container with kubectl and then try to query the health api point - also, slow down your livenessProbe while you check that with `initialDelaySeconds: 120` (in the `livenessProbe`, outside the `httpGet`)

Comment: That works and is pretty simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TomKlino What do you think to post your suggestion as an answer since it solves the issue? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can port-forward to the container with kubectl and then try to query the health api endpoint.

Also, slow down your `livenessProbe` while you check that with `initialDelaySeconds: 120`  (in the `livenessProbe` object, outside the `httpGet`)

Like so:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 80
    scheme: HTTP
```